# Merging two lists where the end result is a list containing same index entries from both parent lists seperated by ',' [PYTHON]

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists:

```
Lat = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Lat = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

And, I want this `Final = [[(1,5), (2,6) ], [(3,7), (4,8)]]`,
where both the lists are separated by `,`

Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice oneliner:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
y = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
result = [[(item[0][idx], item[1][idx]) for idx in range(len(x))] for item in zip(x, y)]
# [[(1, 5), (2, 6)], [(3, 7), (4, 8)]]
```

Which assumes that `x` and `y` have the same length (the assumption occurs where I write `range(len(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ln=[]
 for i,n in enumerate(lat1):
     ln.append([(n[0],lat2[i][0]),(n[1],lat2[i][1])])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()`

```
l1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
l2 = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

res = [[(y[0], y[1]) for y in zip(*x)] for x in zip(l1, l2)]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```